# Indirect dependency vulnerability detected by JFrog XRay

Tags: jfrog-xray

I have a project that uses spring boot 1.3.8.RELEASE, so it contains the dependencies listed here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.3.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-1.3.8.RELEASE.pom

In the list of dependencies you can see `javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA` is included and this version of this component has vulnerabilities.

Anyway in the dependency:tree of the project it is not included neither the jar is downloaded. But JFrog XRay complains my project is vulnerable.

Is there any way in the pom or in a project config file to tell him this dependency is unused so it can be ignored?

Am I wrong and my project is vulnerable as long as it uses a component (spring boot 1.3.8) somehow referring javassist? Can I solve this without upgrading?

** *Please ignore spring boot 1.3.8 has more vulnerabilities, I am focusing in javassist, that I am not using*

Comment: Few questions: How was the project built in Artifactory? What is the version of Xray? maven version?
I recommend using the JFrog CLI jf audit https://docs.jfrog-applications.jfrog.io/jfrog-applications/jfrog-cli/cli-for-jfrog-security/scan-your-source-code
As it is using mvn dependency tree command to get the vulnerabilities and it can see if the issue is in Xray or in the build itself that was published to Artifactory.

Comment: I have no access to these informations, thanks for the recommendation